# jqueryui autocomplete with categories, bad formed input

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, autocomplete

i have a page with a form with a autocomplete widget, the autocomplete had categorires followin the [Documentation](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#categories)

Because i use jquery ui 1.8.12 i change `that._renderItemData( ul, item );` for `that._renderItem( ul, item );`

Also i need pass the `Id` of element, no name, i change

```
{ label: "annttop C13", category: "Products" },
```

to

```
{value:someIdNumeric, label: "annttop C13", category: "Products" },
```

When a type a letter in autocomplete, seems to work well, **but not** when i choose a element input change to `id`, for example:

I choose `many, Cat: food`  inputbox show `24` instead `many`

that I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) says:

> The label property is displayed in the suggestion menu. The value will be inserted into the input element when a user selects an item.

That is exactly what it's doing. It is inserting the value in the input element which is your `id` field.

If you need the `id` field returned when they select, then you need to capture that into another field using the [select event](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select):

```
{id:someIdNumeric, label: "annttop C13", category: "Products" },

$("#your-autocomplete-field").autocomplete({
    source: "your-remote-page.php",
    minLength: 2,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        $('#id-form-field').val(ui.item.id);
        }
    });
```

The field on your form can be `type="hidden"` if need be.

Comment: `select` method not working, i have same behaivor, input had `id` instead `label`, i change `$('#id-form-field').val(ui.item.id);` by `$('#id-form-field').val(ui.item.label);`

Comment: @user3100840 the `$('#id-form-field')` is a form field on your form. Dump `ui.item` to the console and see what is in there on select. `consol.log(ui.item);`